# How do I view the identifier of a folder in the Assets app in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: magnolia

I want to view the identifier of a folder in the Assets app in Magnolia CMS. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the system properties with JCR Browser App

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/JCR+Browser+app

Cheers,

Hope that helps,

Comment: Would you be able to tell me the URL to the JCR Browser app from a browser? I only see the Assets, Pages and Contacts app in the list of apps when I login as superuser on http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor

Comment: From demo instance: https://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:jcr-browser

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the JCR Browser is now titled JCR in Magnolia 6.1x and is accessible from the JCR link under Tools. And there is a filter in the JCR Browser for "dam" and one has to check the "Display system properties" to see the underlying metadata of the folder/asset.